# plotting imaginary data

Tags: list-manipulation

I had a set of data `a5` that had imaginary values but when plotted, that data doesn't shows on the graph.

```
ClearAll[a5,n1]
a5 = {{0.82, 2460}, {1.64, 566}, {1.76,
 485}, {1.95, 385}, {2.06, 339}, {2.24, 274}, {2.47, 214}, {2.74, 
159}, {3.09, 107}, {3.53, 55.9}, {3.80, 21.9}, {3.84, 
15.25}, {3.87, 2.61}, {4.12, 0. + 36*I}, {4.59, 0. + 52*I}, {4.94,
 0. + 55*I}, {5.26, 0. + 56.6*I}, {5.62, 0. + 56.75*I}, {5.83, 
0. + 56.42*I}, {6.18, 0. + 55.48*I}, {6.51, 0. + 54.34*I}, {6.87, 
0. + 52.91*I}};
n1 = ListLinePlot[a5, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 1350}}]
```

I got the plot as shown below where i am missing all the data for `x>3.87`. How could i get the graph for all the values inside the dataset `a5`.

[image]

Comment: Where should e.g. `{4.12, 0. + 36*I}` appear?

Comment: @Kuba , First time I m plotting the imaginary values. So don’t know the value like as 0. + 36*I appears or not?

Comment: Sorry, don't know what do you mean. {4.12, 0. + 36 I} does not belong to `R x R` space. You may want to use `Re` `Im`,  `Abs` or `Arg` etc to convert complex numbers to real, whether that makes sense with your data is impossible to tell without background.

Answer (score 2):

```
   ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ a5, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2,
       Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}}, 
        PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
        PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledCircle]", 15}, {"\[EmptyCircle]", 15}}, 
  PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{"Re", "Im"}, LegendMarkers ->   Automatic],
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Could you please tell me how could i make different color for real and imaginary dots in the last graph. And also i need to make different shape for the real and imaginary dots. Thanks

Comment: @rabink check the updated plot.

Comment: `ReIm` could be used, if version $ \geq 10.1 $.